# Open GL stutter when rendering on Galaxy S2

Tags: android, opengl-es, java-native-interface, galaxy

Our Android game has an issue which appears unique to the Galaxy S2.

Occasionally the render will stutter. By this I mean it basically seems to render the last two frames (as though its swapping the last two render buffers without updating either).

What's really odd about this is that the game continues to update, so say the stutter lasts for 2 seconds, the game will have progressed 2 seconds behind the scenes.

This is odd because our code is basically like this:

```
function Update()
    DoGameLogic()
    DoRender()
```

So this means that if our the game has updated, the game has also rendered. The maximum delta time is capped to 1 frame so there must have been more than one Update and thus multiple renders during the stutter.

My current theory is that on most devices the game lags during render, but on the S2 the render calls are executed but they "fall through" without updating the render buffer.

Has anyone run into this problem? I would really appreciate any suggestions about what this could be.

Answer (score 0):

We found out what the problem is.

The Galaxy S 2 was for some reason running out of GL memory. This wasn't apparent on the devices we were testing with, but on other devices it would crash on some Open GL call - not the offending call mind you.

Eventually we tracked it down to using Point sprite VBO's. As the S 2 is a powerful device, we replaced Point sprites with Quad's mimicking point sprites as a workaround.

Incidentally, SoundPool would also run out of memory on this device, requiring another workaround.